# Even with temperature at 6500K, Redshift seems to "darken" the screen

Tags: display, redshift

I didn't like the fact that Redshift altered my screen temperature on daytime too, so I set it's daytime temperature to 6500K which is supposed to be the "default" temperature. However, the screen still seems to darken a bit, or at least the way colors appear changes, when Redshift is activated compared to normal. Does anyone know what causes this and how it can be prevented?

Answer (score 2):

[Color temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_temperature) does not equal brightness. Simply put, low color temperatures are more yellowish, while higher color temperatures are perceived more blueish.

The color of each pixel on your monitor is typically composed of discrete red, green and blue sub-pixels (and sometimes additional white subpixels to increase maximum brightness). By changing the brightness of each color component, different *perceived colors* can be produced. The *perceived brightness* of a pixel, however, is the sum of the individual components' brightness. If all sub-pixels are at full brightness, the pixel is usually perceived white.

In order to produce a specific color temperature, redshift, as its name implies, shifts all colors such that the result will look more yellowish (lower temperature) or more blueish (higher temperature). Depending on the target temperature, this means *increasing* some color components, while *decreasing* others. The *decrease* inevitably leads to lower perceived brightness.

In your particular case, to achieve 6500K, redshift increases the amount of blue but decreases the amount of red.

In reality, perceived color and brightness are a lot more complicated, but this is AskUbuntu after all.

Comment: Use `xrandr --verbose` does the `Gamma:` line read: `1.0:1.0:1.0`? If not then color modifications are still being set.

Comment: Thanks for the insights on how Redshift alters the colors, however as the comment says I have `1.3:1.3:1.3` as `Gamma`, how do I make Redshift not change the parameters at all during day? It's not even a bad looking effect but I'd like to not have the altered colors at day so I can do color sensitive work.