# How can I apply redshift or sct and not have brightness reset to default in Lubuntu Jammy Jellyfish?

Tags: lubuntu, screen, brightness, redshift

With Windows 10 I can turn on 'nightlight' and adjust the screen brightness with 'nightlight' staying in the 'on' position. But with Lubuntu Jammy Jellyfish if I use 'sct' or Redshift my dimmed brightness reverts to the default position (too bright for me).
I want a warm color tone and very dimmed brightness as I have eye issues. How can I use Redshift or sct and also dim the brightness with Lubuntu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Even with temperature at 6500K, Redshift seems to "darken" the screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115205/even-with-temperature-at-6500k-redshift-seems-to-darken-the-screen)

Comment: I don't really understand the settings of `redshift` etc, so I just manually altered the *conf* or configuration file until I had values & settings that worked for me.  I've since adjusted it maybe twice since  originally setup back in 2015.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Redshift

Comment: Altering the *conf* file is working well. I am using extended monitors - (1) laptop screen with (2) external VGA monitor. Altering the *conf* file seems to affect both equally. Is there a way to configure each screen separately?

Comment: It is my understanding that changes will impact all screens via the signals sent to them, and `redshift` does not provide any mechanism to target any particularly screen thru X.org. Lubuntu using LXQt which is a *light* desktop, does not provide any such feature (*intentionally as it would add weight (likely requiring KF5/6) which would fit the light aim*)

Comment: I can tilt the laptop screen to more of an angle to darken it (sometimes a cheap screen pays off!). The physical buttons/firmware for the external VGA are not easy to use so I generally leave those settings where they are. This is a great solution. The laptop is a bit sluggish with Windows 10 but quite acceptable with Lubuntu because of the, as you say, OS's lightness.

Comment: I created a desktop symlink for *redshift.config* and dragged that onto the taskbar. This makes adjusting pretty easy.